# How to extract last field column three only having numbers

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to get the third column and in particular wants to extract dates only, below is what the data looks like.

## Example dataset

```
health status index                           uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   dpc-syslog-2019.02.04           HJNqQMd_T1qbyHM5HEHGUw   5   1   46559620            0     37.1gb         18.5gb
green  open   syslog-2019.06.23               Q73bPEXUQz64Pt7eh-a3pQ   5   1       4930            0      2.1mb            1mb
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-6-2019.02.04 _5_68NpKStWo3dBFOXZUlw   1   1       8749            0        5mb          2.5mb
green  open   syslog-2019.04.11               e45heIjRTGqO_KHS8He0Ag   5   1         14            0      109kb         54.5kb
green  open   syslog-2019.02.04               -tshSKMAR8GKYnY2KSqn_Q   5   1   19236875            0        5gb          2.5gb
green  open   syslog-2019.05.04               cTgQAcT-QkKklhsKucvotA   5   1         14            0      141kb         70.5kb
green  open   syslog-2019.04.19               CXzRauBZTWu64HB8KTCj5A   5   1         14            0    108.9kb         54.4kb
green  open   syslog-2019.03.02               ap9TDVkIQeGRbTQ9Qpzarg   5   1         14            0    108.3kb         54.1kb
green  open   syslog-2019.03.03               uNcOfR8gSfWYWJgh1Bp9WQ   5   1         14            0    107.6kb         53.8kb
```

Below is what i tried to get the dates but i sees in my below command syntax it has some character strings as well to which i would like to remove.

## Attempted code :

```
[root@host1 ~]# curl -s -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v | awk '{print $3}'|cut -d. -f1-3 | sed 's/\.//g' | awk -F- '{print $NF}' | head
index
kibana
20190204
20190623
20190204
20190411
20190204
20190504
20190419
20190302
20190303
```

## Desired output :

```
20190204
20190623
20190204
20190411
20190204
20190504
20190419
20190302
20190303
```

Saying that , i want only numbers and just want to skip of delete any char strings like `index` in above code.

I hope this can better and cleanly done with either awk or sed or grep but just fiddling around the way to achieve.

thanks for your help.

Comment: 1. What output are you trying to get?  2. Why are you using awk and cut and sed and awk again? Shouldn't this be a single awk command?

Comment: @melpomene, i just updated the post , though i needed only numbers

Comment: _last field only having numbers_ seems to be all zeros.

Comment: @Tiw, thats there in my command  output ,  just consider that pls

Comment: @JamesBrown, looks like title of the post was misleading i tried to make it more clear now, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Tiw, i might got it from some sort so please just consider that way :-)

Comment: @Tiw, just updated , uses Attempted code

Comment: @Tiw, you Just leave that and take the example dataset for testing , sorry for not making it clear enough :(  , updated, you are right.

Comment: Btw, your attempt **do** output `201902` on the third data line, so your edit to change that one is not correct, however thanks for your patience, maybe it's also because of me didn't point out the inconsistency clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another GNU awk way:

```
awk '$3~/[0-9]{4}/{print gensub(/.*-|[^0-9]*/, "", "g", $3)}'
```

You can finetune the regex base on different situations, basically accuracy trade off with conciseness.

And GNU sed solution:

```
sed -E '/(\S*\s+){2}.*[0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]{2}){2}/!d; s/(\S*\s+){2}(\S*\s+).*/\2/g; s/.*-|[^0-9]*//g'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one way:

```
$ awk '$3~/[0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]{2}){2}$/{gsub(/^.*-|[^0-9]/,"",$3);print $3}' file
20190204
20190623
20190204
...
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '$3~/[0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]{2}){2}$/ {  # picking records on regex
    gsub(/^.*-|[^0-9]/,"",$3)           # remove all before last dash and non-digits
    print $3                            # output
}' file
```

Comment: woah! nice regex!

Comment: Great indeed +1 , however i'm getting some blank lines & numbers like `1`  only in the line print, can that be trimmed.

Comment: Blank lines come from fields that have no numbers, I'll remove them in a sec. Do you want just 8 digit numbers or what?

Comment: Now it expects `$3` to end with YYYY.MM-DD.

Comment: @JamesBrown,  Correct :-)

Comment: If you want a header, add `BEGIN{print "header"}`to the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'sub(/.*-/,"",$3){gsub(/\./,"",$3); print $3}' file
20190204
20190623
20190204
20190411
20190204
20190504
20190419
20190302
20190303
```

Comment: Very nice, elegant, and compatible way :-)

Comment: Very nice @Ed Morton as always!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($3,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){val=substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/\./,"",val);print val}' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '{sub(/.*-/,"",$3);gsub(/\./,"",$3);print $3}'  Input_file
```

Comment: This works but just looking if we can have more shorter way :-)

Comment: @pygo, sure please try my 2nd solution now.

Comment: second solution gives error `unexpected newline or end of string`

Comment: @pygo, sure, fixed the typo now.

Answer (score 1):

With `tail`, `cut` and `tr`:

```
<infile tail -n+2 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3 | rev | cut -d- -f1 | rev | tr -d .
```

Comment: Nice one with tr & tail , cut +1

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl one-liner also

```
perl -lane ' if($.>1) { $F[2]=~/.*\-(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/ and print "$1$2$3" } '
```

or

```
perl -lane ' if($.>1) { $F[2]=~/.*\-(\S+)/ and ($t=$1)=~tr/\.//d and print $t  } '
```

Since the header doesn't match the date pattern, the check on line number ($.) can also be removed.

```
perl -lane ' $F[2]=~/.*\-(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/ and print "$1$2$3"  '
```

with your inputs

```
$ cat pygo.txt
health status index                           uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   dpc-syslog-2019.02.04           HJNqQMd_T1qbyHM5HEHGUw   5   1   46559620            0     37.1gb         18.5gb
green  open   syslog-2019.06.23               Q73bPEXUQz64Pt7eh-a3pQ   5   1       4930            0      2.1mb            1mb
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-6-2019.02.04 _5_68NpKStWo3dBFOXZUlw   1   1       8749            0        5mb          2.5mb
green  open   syslog-2019.04.11               e45heIjRTGqO_KHS8He0Ag   5   1         14            0      109kb         54.5kb
green  open   syslog-2019.02.04               -tshSKMAR8GKYnY2KSqn_Q   5   1   19236875            0        5gb          2.5gb
green  open   syslog-2019.05.04               cTgQAcT-QkKklhsKucvotA   5   1         14            0      141kb         70.5kb
green  open   syslog-2019.04.19               CXzRauBZTWu64HB8KTCj5A   5   1         14            0    108.9kb         54.4kb
green  open   syslog-2019.03.02               ap9TDVkIQeGRbTQ9Qpzarg   5   1         14            0    108.3kb         54.1kb
green  open   syslog-2019.03.03               uNcOfR8gSfWYWJgh1Bp9WQ   5   1         14            0    107.6kb         53.8kb
$ perl -lane ' if($.>1) { $F[2]=~/.*\-(\S+)/ and ($t=$1)=~tr/\.//d and print $t  } ' pygo.txt
20190204
20190623
20190204
20190411
20190204
20190504
20190419
20190302
20190303
$
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr 's/^(\S+\s+){2}\S+(....)\.(..)\.(..)\s+.*/\2\3\4/p' file
```

Pattern match on the third column, only printing when a match is successful.